# Не выставляются привилегии пользователя

Tags: mysql, sql

Добрый вечер.

Для создания пользователя и назначения ему привилегий, выполняю следующую команду:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON `tb_users`.* TO 'hello'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '12345' WITH MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0 MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0;
```

Затем захожу во вкладку Привилегии, панели PhpMyAdmin и вижу там добавленного пользователя с привилегиями USAGE, что означает отсутствие у него привилегий. Но ведь я указал в запросе **SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE**. Почему не выставились привилегии?

Comment: 'hello'@'localhost' - тут с кавычками всё нормально?

Comment: Да, кавычки проверил. Вроде всё нормально. В данный момент пробую добавлять пользователя напрямую, через INSERT INTO. Посмотрим что из этого получится.

Comment: а вы не через обёртку спросите, а напрямую у сервера: `show grants for 'hello'@'localhost'`

Comment: А я зашёл в таблицу `user` и проверил добавленную запись c привилегиями `Select_priv, Insert_priv , Update_priv, Delete_priv`. Везде стоял "N" - нет привилегий.

Answer (score 1):

Вот что у меня получилось с добавлением пользователей используя обычные операции INSERT INTO и DELETE.

```
// ИЗБИРАЕМ БАЗУ ДАННЫХ

if(!mysql_select_db('mysql', $link)) { exit; }

// УДАЛЯЕМ СТАРОГО ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ

$mysql_old_user_server = "localhost";
$mysql_old_user_login = "hello";
$exist_old_user = mysql_query("SELECT `user` FROM `user` WHERE `Host`='".$mysql_old_user_server."' AND `User`='".$mysql_old_user_login."'");
if(mysql_num_rows($exist_old_user) > 0) {
    $delete_old_user_privileges = "DELETE FROM `db` WHERE `Host`='".$mysql_old_user_server."' AND `User`='".$mysql_old_user_login."' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($delete_old_user_privileges);
    $delete_old_user = "DELETE FROM `user` WHERE `Host`='".$mysql_old_user_server."' AND `User`='".$mysql_old_user_login."' LIMIT 1";
    mysql_query($delete_old_user);
}   

// ДОБАВЛЯЕМ НОВОГО ПОЛЬЗОВАТЕЛЯ

$mysql_new_user_server = "localhost";
$mysql_new_user_login = "new_hello";
$mysql_new_user_pass = "1234";
$insert_user = "INSERT INTO `user` (`Host`,`User`,`Password`,`Select_priv`,`Insert_priv`,`Update_priv`,`Delete_priv`,`ssl_cipher`,`x509_issuer`,`x509_subject`,`authentication_string`) VALUES ('".$mysql_new_user_server."','".$mysql_new_user_login."',PASSWORD('".$mysql_new_user_pass."'), 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', 'Y', '', '', '', '')";
$insert_user_privileges = "INSERT INTO `db` (`Host`,`Db`,`User`,`Select_priv`,`Insert_priv`,`Update_priv`,`Delete_priv`) VALUES ('".$mysql_new_user_server."','cardmini','".$mysql_new_user_login."','Y','Y','Y','Y')";
if(mysql_query($insert_user) && mysql_query($insert_user_privileges)) {
    mysql_query("FLUSH PRIVILEGES");
}
```